# What do I do to make Sublime text stop ignoring filenames that start with a dot

Tags: sublimetext3

I am using Sublime Text editor and I need to change the settings for Sublime 3 to open files that start with a dot like .gitignore. Please let me know where in the settings I need to make the change. I am using Windows OS fyi.

Comment: You can enable the *Show hidden and system files* option in Windows explorer.

Comment: Thanks @MattDMo I was getting so frustrated thinking it was a setting in Sublime.

Comment: No worries, glad to help. Do you want me to make it an official answer you can accept?

Comment: Sure, that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a Sublime-specific option, but an operating system one, as the OS determines what is displayed in file dialogs as well as the file system explorer. To set the option on Windows, first open Windows Explorer and navigate to the folder containing the dotfile you want to view. Then, in the *View* tab, click the <kbd>Options</kbd> button on the far right, then select <kbd>Change folder and search options</kbd>.

[image: View → Options]

You can also find *Options* under the *File* menu.

The Options window will now pop up. Select the *View* tab, then select the option *Show hidden files, folders, and drives*. Next, click on the <kbd>Apply to Folders</kbd> button at the top.

[image: Options window]

Similar options are also available on [macOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99213/is-it-possible-to-always-show-hidden-dotfiles-in-open-save-dialogs) and [Linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/258642/hidden-files-always-being-shown).